# Spring Security gives error when trying to log out from website

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security

Hello I am building a web app and I just implemented the ability to log in and register, now the problem is logging out..

I have a button which calls this function to log out:

```
const logoutUser = () => {
        axios({
            url: API.logout,
            method: "POST",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": _csrf.token,
            },
        });
    };
```

And this is my Spring Security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/getalltopics").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/findtopicbycodename/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/createtopic").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/me").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/registeruser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/dologoutuser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/getcsrftoken").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("http://192.168.1.105:3000/", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/dologoutuser")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        http.cors(withDefaults());
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://192.168.1.105:3000"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/dologoutuser", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }
```

(Yes i know you can put multiple links into single .antMatchers, this code is currently being worked on)

Now when I hit the log out button, I get 3 errors in my console :

1.`OPTIONS http://192.168.1.105:8080/login?logout 403`

2.`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.105:8080/login?logout' (redirected from 'http://192.168.1.105:3000/dologoutuser') from origin 'http://192.168.1.105:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

3.`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)`

Also, if I refresh the page with F5 after clicking the logout button, it actually logs me out, but obviously I'm doing something wrong here. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer...

The logout was successful and it was redirecting me to some random URL which was actually forbidden by Spring Security. To fix this, I just added a logout success url and everything works flawlessly now.

`http.logoutSuccessUrl("http://192.168.1.105:3000/")`

Answer (score 0):

You configured your cors allowed origins wrong.
You should add 192.168.1.105 (or the host where your reactjs app is hosted) as allowed origin, not /dologoutuser

Comment: Oh. Do I put the /dologoutuser into the `source` then instead of `/**`?

Comment: The docs say _Register a CorsConfiguration for the specified path pattern._  for _registerCorsConfiguration_. So if you want the cors config to only apply to that path then yes. If the config should be used for all your other paths then /** is fine.

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestion but I am still getting the exact same error